# Can QGIS be used to calculate the up-slopes (total area draining to a specified point) of multiple separate points simultaneously?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, point, vector

I am trying to calculate the area draining to a point of 240 separate points using QGIS. At the moment I'm using the Saga - Upslope Area algorithm to individually work this out for each of the 240 points using their coordinates and a DEM input. This is very time-consuming so is there is a quicker more efficient algorithm which would allow me to input the whole vector file for the point data to simultaneously output the upslopes for all the points at once?

Comment: From memory I don't think this is possible with the Saga Upslope tool. You could try and batch process it by loading all open layers. If all 240 points are in a single shapefile then you will have to split the features into separate layers. I have never tried this but it might work.

Comment: You could also try running this using the SAGA command prompt outside of QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since you asked this question, but I thought I will post the answer anyway since it may help someone who will stumble upon your question.

There is no tool in QGIS yet that can do that, however, you can achieve that with a script. I have posted a script here - [Qgis SAGA Upslope Area for several points automation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342333/qgis-saga-upslope-area-for-several-points-automation/348816#348816). 
Hope that helps.